# Is it possible to break on a breakpoint only when a certain method is present in the call stack?

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, lldb

Suppose I have a method `foo` that gets called by different methods, when going through a hierarchy of object.

Is it possible to break inside method `foo`, only when it was called by method `bar` (so `bar` is present in the call stack)?

Does LLDB or GDB support such a use-case?

Comment: Why dont you put your breakpoint where `bar()` calls `foo()`?

Comment: @YSC I've often had situations where the stack between `bar` and `foo` is quite deep. I mean, `bar` calls `a` which calls `b` which calls `c` which ... eventually calls `foo`.

Comment: @Angew I see. Maybe OP should edit it's question to let us know if (s)he is in this situation.

Comment: @YSC : That is kind of what the title and first paragraph suggests, but then the second paragraph is explicit that foo is called from bar - but perhaps that was unintentional to imply that.  Either way the same solution applies.

Comment: @YSC : also it may be that it is not a simple breakpoint on `foo()` but a breakpoint somewhere within `foo()` that is executed conditionally.

Comment: Yes, in my situation the call stack between foo and bar can be big, as well as with different functions calling and data. Basically it's nested event handling, and using a simple breakpoint in either place would not be acceptable because of multiple breaks in the wrong moments. Whereas I would like to break only in a particular case when I know which additional functions should be present in the call stack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recent versions of gdb ship with some convenience functions written in Python for just this case.  Take a look at `$_caller_is` and friends.  (FWIW this exact use case was what motivated me to work on adding Python to gdb...)

A simple use would be:

```
(gdb) break foo if $_any_caller_matches("bar")
```

If the call stack contains more functions in between `foo` and `bar` calls  resulting in a stack that looks like the following,

```
foo()
...
...
...
bar()
...
...
...
main()
```

you could pass an extra argument to `_any_caller_matches` which indicates the number of frames to check for the occurrence of `bar`

```
(gdb) break foo if $_any_caller_matches("bar", 10)
```

Reference: https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Convenience-Funs.html

> $_any_caller_matches(regexp[, number_of_frames])
>
> Returns one if any
> calling function’s name matches the regular expression regexp.
> Otherwise it returns zero.
>
> If the optional argument number_of_frames is provided, it is the
> number of frames up in the stack to look. The default is 1.
>
> This function differs from $_caller_matches in that this function
> checks all stack frames from the immediate caller to the frame
> specified by number_of_frames, whereas $_caller_matches only checks
> the frame specified by number_of_frames.

Comment: That looks like what I was looking for, thank you!
Only issue would be to find a similar construct for lldb, and it doesn't seem to be the case that lldb supports that.

Answer (score 3):

The way you would do this in lldb is to write a Python based breakpoint command that checks the stack of the thread that hit the breakpoint, and continues if it doesn't contain a frame with that function.  The breakpoint commands tell lldb to stop or not by returning True or False respectively from the function.  So a very simplistic way to do this would be to make a Python file (break_here.py):

```
import lldb
desired_func = "some_func"
def break_here(frame, bp_loc, dict):
    thread = frame.thread
    for frame in thread.frames:
        if frame.name == desired_func:
            return True
    return False
```

Suppose this file is in /tmp.  Then in lldb you do:

```
(lldb) com scr imp /tmp/break_here.py
(lldb) br s -n whatever
(lldb) br com add --python-function break_here.break_here
```

Answer (score 2):

In GDB you can associate a debugger [command list](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Break-Commands.html) to a breakpoint, so to achieve  your aim, you could place a breakpoint in `bar()` where it calls `foo()` with a command list that that sets a breakpoint in `foo()` and continues.  A further breakpoint in `bar()` *after* its call to `foo()` will be required to clear the breakpoint in `foo()`.

So:

```
int bar()
{
    foo() ;     // Add breakpoint with command list here to set breakpoint in foo()
    return 0 ;  // Add breakpoint command list here to clear breakpoint in foo()
}
```

Of course if this happens very infrequently, you could set the breakpoints manually.

If `foo()` is not called directly from `bar()` or perhaps `foo()` is called from multiple places in `bar()`, then the same solution applies; it is sufficient to set the breakpoint at the start if `bar()` and clear it at the end.

One caveat; if the application is multi-threaded and either `bar()` or `foo()` may be called from more than one thread, then you will need a [thread specific breakpoint](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Thread_002dSpecific-Breakpoints.html).

Comment: That looks like a good workaround to achieve the result, but @Tom Tromey's answer seems to provide a more developer-friendly solution.

Comment: @Placinta : I agree, I am no gdb expert. The method I have suggested is one I have used in other debuggers, and may be more portable.